# Is it safe to skip [Authorize] attribute on a particular controller API for optional authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I have an existing ASP.NET Core MVC application that I want to add a new API method in a controller. I want to touch the authentication/authorization code as little as possible, so I don't want to write a new authentication middleware for this one API.

The method is supposed to return some type of data if the user is anonoymous/unknown. And it should return more specific and potentially personal information if the user is signed in and has a valid user.

Is it safe to skip the [Authorize] attribute, and check only check the HttpContext.User (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.8) property for the username?

Can I assume that the signature has been verified by the OpenID Connect middleware?

```cs
// No Authorize attribute
public IActionResult MyApi()
{
    string userName = System.Security.Claims.Claim idClaim = this.HttpContext.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "sub")?.Value;
    // Can I assume that the User object only is non-null if the OAuth signature is actually verified?
    // Or is fake-cookies possible?
}
```

Comment: If you want anonymous users access the the API then just use `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. That mean everybody!  But if you need different kinds of authenticated users receive different kind of responses then I think you should use Policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization does not do anything in regards to authentification, it's only a mechanism to check whether the **authenticated** user has access to the requested resource. It's like a layer on top of authentication.

The presence of `HttpContext.User` does not necessarily indicate an authenticated user, but `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` does. For `ClaimsIdentity` it basically just checks whether the field `AuthenticationType` is not empty.

Therefore, it's safe to assume the user *is authenticated* if it has `AuthenticationType` field set. It's also safe to assume that if the field `Name` is not empty as unauthenticated users can't have it set.

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom extensions method to read the username from the current identity:

```
public static bool TryGetUserName(this IIdentity identity, out string username)
{
    try
    {
        username = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserName(identity);
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
    {
        username = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I use this extension in my API method by calling:

```
bool isAuth = this.User?.Identity?.TryGetUserName(out username) ?? false;
```

Comment: Thanks for input!I have an extension method for this, but I copied out the code from it for this question to simplify it.